# BIND9 and external domain

Tags: dns

I need a little help concerning the configuration of BIND 9 in Ubuntu server 12.04.2.
We have a domain `company.com` with an external registrar. With this, we can manage all DNS settings for the website (www.company.com) which is in a VPS on the Internet.

Now we need to also have the crm application (crm.company.com) accessible from the Internet. However, CRM is on a Linux server in our LAN, different from the one using BIND 9.

How can I configure my BIND to manage the `crm.company.com` request and forward it to the correct server?

**Edit - based on addtional help from mr. douggro**

I try to explain better my IT structure concernig mr. douggro suggestion:

PUBLIC REGISTRAR => Manage DNS entry for company.com

INTERMEDIATE SRV => My server with BIND9, IpTbales, eth0 on WAN, eth1 on LAN(10.1.1.120)

WEB SRV => My server with apache, mysql, php5 eth0 on LAN (10.1.1.122) where crm run

Answer (score 0):

There should be nothing you need to do with your BIND configuration. With your DNS being managed through your domain registrar, you should be able to enter a new A Record for `crm.company.com` that points to the public IP address of your LAN router.
`crm.company.com IN A 12.34.56.789`
Apache on your Linux server will need to be configured to handle requests for `crm.company.com` as a virtual host if the server is not already assigned that hostname.

You will need to configure your LAN router to open and forward necessary ports (like 80 and 8080 for http and https) to the internal LAN IP address of the Linux server.

This works fine if your LAN router is working with a static public IP address. If your router is using a dynamic public IP address, it gets more complicated and you will need to investigate using a dynamic DNS service like dyn.com to manage the DNS for your `crm.company.com` domain and configure your primary DNS to point to the dynamic DNS service for resolving the subdomain.

**Edit - based on addtional info from comments**

Since you have an intermediate server acting as a router and running BIND that you want to manage resolving a subdomain, and your primary DNS is being managed through your domain registrar, the resolution to your desired configuration gets a little complicated. Registrars rarely support subdomain DNS services, expecting that either you or your hosting provider handle any subdomain delegation.

The simplest solution I can think of for your desired configuration is to, if possible, run BIND on your VPS and have that become the authoritative host for your domain. You would then need to add an A Record in BIND on the VPS server for your intermediate server after giving it a FQDN and hostname (`company.local` will not work - it needs to be something like `zones.company.com` to be resolvable externally.) An additional PTR Record on the VPS for the `crm.company.com` server should also point to your intermediate server. Then BIND on the intermediate server should be set up with a Master Zone for `zones.company.com` and add an A Record to it pointing to the LAN IP of the `crm` server:  `crm.company.com IN A 10.1.1.122`
You will need to make sure that IPTABLES allows forwarding and pass-through of the ports needed for your CRM system.

Comment: HI douqqro. Thnak's for replay. It's no so simple. We have a server with BIND9 and IPTABLES and 2 eth (red and green) and a second server on which the CRM is running. So i can not use apache on the first server. The must is that BIND9 can forward the query on the right server

Comment: @Giacall99 What domain(s) is the BIND server authoritative for? And how does it interface to the WAN - with a public IP address?

Comment: @douqqro => Thank's for your time. Well, in my BIND i've configured only a master zone company.local. And yes.. we have a public static IP address.

Comment: So you have an intermediate server not hosting `crm` running BIND with only a `company.local` master zone on your LAN linked through a second NIC port to the server running `crm`, and that intermediate server is also handling your internal LAN IP routing via IPTABLES?

Comment: @douqqro => Yes. It's correct. In the intermediate server (eth0 wan, eth1 lan) run iptables, BIND9, DHCP local IP 10.1.1.120. BIND9 with a master zone company.local. In other server (eth0 lan) with local IP 10.1.1.122 run a web application for crm.

Comment: => Thank for your time.. I've edited my question concerning your suggestion, trying to explain better my IT structure. But let me understand.. I must install a bind9 also in my WEB SRV? And if so... How i must set the A record in my external resgistrar? I must create the zones.company.com in both server (intermediate and webserver) or only in one of them? And the crm.company.com is the master zone in webserver? It's correct? I'm a little bit confused

Comment: BIND would need to be running on your VPS server and intermediate server, with DNS records that form a chain pointing to your web server hosting `crm.company.com` The chain would be Domain Registrar=>VPS `company.com` =>Intermediate Server `zones.company.com`=>web server `crm.company.com`  If you can't install BIND on the VPS, your options are to either move the CRM to the VPS, or ditch the VPS and move the all your domains to your internal servers.

Comment: something like... **REGISTRAR** => `company.com` A IP_VPS. **VPS** => `zones.company.com` A IP_MY_BIND_SRV (INERMEDIATE). **INTERMEDIATE** => `crm.company.com` A MY_LOCAL_WEBSRV_IP (10.1.1.122). It's correct?? In my VPS i've a dns server installed for the local zone... It's no possible to bypass the VPS? Something like: REGISTRAR => ns.company.com A IP_MY_BIND_SRV and zone.company.com NS ns.company.com. INTERMEDIATE => zone.company.com and crm.company.com A MY_LOCAL_WEBSRV_IP (10.1.1.122)??

Comment: Your registrar sets up a DNS entry to point to your domain. It most likely is pointing to the name servers for your VPS provider which then point to your VPS instance. You might be able to get your VPS provider to add DNS records that point to your intermediate server to resolve it and the `crm`. If they won't do it, BIND on the VPS will have to have the records to have your subdomains resolve through DNS in the chain I described.